# What are OS Types for video formats other than MooV in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, quicktime

I've followed [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication.html) to get a Cocoa application that plays mov files in a window using the QuickTime Movie View control. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework.html) documentation page says that QTKit supports other file formats such as AVI and MPEG-4. I'm not able to open files of that type from the **File>Open...** dialog though.

I have a hunch that I just have to add the right Document Type to my target and then the Open... dialog will allow me to open AVI files, but I don't know what to put in the **OS Type** field. Am I on the right track? Where can I get a list of a bunch of possible OS Types for video formats?

Bonus: What does MooV stand for anyway, some sort of cow movie?

Comment: MooV is the (ancient) type code for QuickTime movies. Type codes always had 4 characters. http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25699?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html), `CFBundleTypeOSTypes` (OS Types) has been deprecated as of Mac OS 10.5. You (and that tutorial) should be using [Uniform Type Identifiers (UTIs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/index.html) instead.

Apple provide a [list of system-declared Uniform Type Identifiers (UTIs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html). For instance, AVI and MPEG-4 files are identified by the `public.avi` and `public.mpeg-4` UTIs, both of which conform to the `public.movie` UTI.

Comment: It looks like this is what I'm supposed to have in the info.plist dialog: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html in my version of XCode (3.2.3 PreRelease), there's no column for UTI. I'm updating to 3.2.5 now, we'll see if that works.

Comment: Awesome, that worked; I just added a new DocumentType with a UTI of public.avi and now my app can open avis! thanks!